# How to override PHP configuration when running in CGI mode

Tags: php, windows, apache, configuration, cgi

There are some tutorials out there telling me how to override PHP configuration when it is running in CGI mode. But I'm still confused because lots of them assume that the server is running on Linux. While I need to do that **also** on Windows.

My hosting is indeed using Linux but my local development computer is using Windows XP with Xampp 1.7.3. So I need to do that in my local computer first, then I want to change the configuration on hosting server.

The PHP in my hosting server is already run as CGI while in my local computer still run as Apache module.

At this point, the processes that I understand are:

1. Change PHP to work in CGI mode. I did this by commenting these two line in "httpd-xampp.conf":

   > `# LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"`
   >   `# LoadModule php5_module modules/php5apache2_2.dll`
2. My PHP is now running as CGI. I checked this with phpinfo(). It tells me that the Server API is now CGI/FastCGI. Now I want to override php configuration.
3. Create "cgi-bin" directory in DocumentRoot. My DocumentRoot is in "D:\www\" (I'm using apache with virtual host). So it is now "D:\www\cgi-bin".
4. Change the default "cgi-bin" directory settings from "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/" to "D:\www\cgi-bin":

   > `ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "D:/www/cgi-bin/"`
   >
   > ```
   > <Directory "D:\www\cgi-bin">
   >    Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch Includes ExecCGI
   >    AllowOverride All
   >    Allow from All
   > </Directory>
   > ```
5. Copy 'php.ini' file to "D:\www\cgi-bin" and modify upload_max_filesize setting from 128M to 10M.
6. Create 'php.cgi' file in "D:\www\cgi-bin" and put these code inside the file:

   > `#!/bin/sh`
   >   `/usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php5 -c /home/user/public_html/cgi-bin/`

That's it. I'm stuck at this point. All of tutorials tell me to create 'php.cgi' file and put shell code inside the file.

How to do the 6th step on Windows? I know the next step is to create handler in .htaccess file to load that 'php.cgi'.

And also, because I will also need to change PHP configuration on my hosting server (Linux), is the 6th step above right? Some tutorial tells to insert these lines instead of above:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PHPRC=/site/ini/1
exec /cgi-bin/php5.cgi
```

I'm sorry if my question is not clear. I'm a new member and this is my first question in this site.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you see this? http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php#60737

Comment: Well written question.  However in point (2) you are most likely setting up the PHP apache module instead, not a CGI interpreter. Hence further CGI setup steps seem redundant. Just check phpinfo() again to see where it expects the php.ini to reside, and use that. Your settings are not picked up, unless you restart Apache (because it's using mod_php). Also let me quickly disapprove of the Windows usage..

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Do you mean in point (1) I already change PHP to work in CGI then in point (2) I change back to apache module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is already running PHP as cgi, and you do not need to run multiple PHP configurations, steps 5 and 6 are not necessary. Just change the default php.ini

Comment: Yeah I know we could directly edit the default php.ini file. But we can't do that on hosting server.

Comment: There is no sure-fire way to affect php configuration on a hosting server (I am assuming you are talking about a third-party host.) Some hosts prevent that entirely. Others allow you to have your own php.ini file in a certain location. Other allow changes via .htaccess file, e.g.

php_value upload_max_filesize 10M

Comment: Yes Svemir. I'm using third-party host. Actually I have written some php configuration in .htaccess. But it don't work because my hosting server sets PHP to run in CGI mode.

Comment: If your system has a main setup or configuration file that is always loaded, certain php.ini directives can be overridden with ini_set() function.