# Alternative way of uploading files when unable to alter php.ini settings

Tags: file-upload, php

I have a site hosts on a shared server and the hosts will not let me alter the php.ini file.

If the upload takes more than 60 seconds then it errors because the `max_input_time` is set to 60 and can't be altered in any way I can think of. The `upload_max_filesize` is set to 100 too which may cause problems too.

Is there an alternative way to do this which gets around this problem?

Comment: Which of the other ways to override ini settings per-directory have you explored? Are CGI setups possible?

Comment: You could always upload to a separate server..

Comment: I've tried a .htaccess file and also adding code into the php page itself to override - `ini_set("max_input_time", "1000000");`

Answer (score 0):

To be clear your host won't allow you to have your own local php.ini file or did you mean they won't change it in the main php.ini file for the server?

If you are allowed to use a local php.ini file then you can override that directive.

Comment: Where would place a local php.ini file in order to test this?

Comment: Put it in the directory where the script is.

Comment: My hosts have told me the only way around this is to upgrade my hosting as PHP all runs off the main configuration file only.

Comment: Unless you are currently getting free hosting then I think I'd find a new host.  There are too many good hosts around to be paying money and not getting what you should be.

Comment: No not at all. Depends on the experience level of the administrators of each hosting company.  Ones new to the business may not know how to set it up whereas established hosting companies will have the experience needed to enable it for their customers.

Comment: I know for example the hosting company I've been using for the last decade supports this and doesn't require you to pay to "upgrade" to this feature.

Comment: You hosting company being...??

Answer (score 0):

> For experienced users only

Usually one can set up a custom PHP interpreter as CGI handler. There are many caveats, and it easily becomes a security issue. Before doing so it's crucial to *study*:

> http://php.net/manual/en/security.cgi-bin.php

Such an interpreter should preferrably not go into `/cgi-bin/`, or be covered by `RewriteRule`s, only invoked by an Apache `Action` handler.

But then this allows to host a custom `php.ini` just for that interpreter. If it doesn't accept it in the same directory, a shell wrapper for the interpreter would do. [How to override PHP configuration when running in CGI mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581360/how-to-override-php-configuration-when-running-in-cgi-mode)